# RxSwift: ensuring current thread in subscribe closure

Tags: swift, multithreading, rx-swift

The question is very simple. Is it guaranteed that, without calling `observeOn()` - i.e. using `CurrentThreadScheduler` - the closure of `subscribe()` is executed in the same **thread** (not queue) of the call?

In the example *starting thread* == *observer thread*

```
// <starting thread>
let observable = ... // an observable
observable.subscribe(onNext: { _ in
    // <observer thread>
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's said [here](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/rxswift-examples-4-multithreading/) that

> When we are doing some operations with Rx, by definition it is all done on the same thread. Unless you don’t change the thread manually, entry point of the chain will begin on the current thread and it will also dispose on the same thread.

Also, the default scheduler is the CurrentThreadScheduler, which schedules on the current thread